# How to Store and Parse RRULE data

Tags: php, date, recursion, calendar, fullcalendar

I'm sure this has been asked a few times around here, but I haven't found a decent solution, or understanding the best way to do this.

I have a calendar (using jQuery FullCalendar). And I want to implement a recurrence structure to the calendar. The best way would be to use a standard, such as iCal RRULE.

But what i'm trying to figure out is, what is the best way to store it in a MySQL database?
A simple (varchar field), containing: RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=TU,WE,FR;UNTIL=20110713T075959Z;WKST=SU

Once I have it 'stored' in the database, how would I go about 'pulling' the data from the database to parse the recurrence to display onto my calendar?

EDIT: Along with making an event, never stop repeating, IE a birthday?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

You can interpret RRule strings on the client side with the Javascript library [RRule.js](https://github.com/jkbr/rrule)
like so:

```
var holidays = RRule.fromString("FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=MO,FR;INTERVAL=5;UNTIL=20130130T230000Z");
var datesToHighlight = RRule.between( calendarViewStartDate, calendarViewEndDate);
```

Comment: Oh wow, that's handy... do you know of anything for PHP as well?

Comment: There's a PHP conversion of the rrule.js scripts here: https://github.com/simshaun/recurr

Answer (score 2):

I suppose this answer is way too late for the poster, but for other people browsing (like me), [this PHP library](https://github.com/simshaun/recurr) seems promising. As the description says, it is heavily inspired by rrule.js.

*Edit:*
Oh, I forgot to link to [this library](https://github.com/tplaner/When) which also handles recursive dates and also looks viable for the purpose.

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion, it does look not to bad in my quick scan there...!! I haven't implemented a solid solution for any form of recurrence yet, so this is still a big issue for me. Thanks for the information!